# Asignarle un nombre fijo al subir la imagen con Intervention

Tags: laravel, intervention

Tengo el siguiente código que asigana de manera automática el nombre de mi archivo, un grupo aleatorio de caracteres, pero en esta oportunidad debo asignarle un nombre fijo a esa imagen, ejemplo: background y no veo en la documentación como hacerlo.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $text = Text::find($id);

    $text->fill($request->all())->save(); 

    if($request->file('image')){

        $file = $request->file('image');
        $img = Image::make($file);
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('img/app',  $file);
        $img->save($path);
    }

    return redirect()->route('text.index')->with('info', 'Texto actualizado con éxito');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$path="/img/app";
$file = $request->file('image');
$imagename = 'backgorund.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
//$name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$public_path = public_path($path);
$picture= \Image::make($file);
// a la hora del darle el save solo le colocamos otro nombre
$picture->save($public_path.'/'.$imagename,100);
```

o puedes hacerlo sin Intevertion:

```
$path="/img/app";
$file = $request->file('image'); 
$imagename = 'backgorund.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();      
$public_path= public_path($path);
$file->move($public_path, $imagename);
```

Comment: No me funcionó, la segunda me dice que con Drive GD no funciona, lo cambié a Imagick y tampoco funcionó ->move

Comment: Listo, gracias!